# How to catch warning messages in function embedded with another function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to catch a warning message in a function (testA) embedded with another function (testB) which also contain a warning message. When I try to catch the warning message in testA, ME variable is not generated. 
To simplify, I have defined both tests :
Test A

```
function testA()
    warning('testA');
    testB();
end
```

TestB

```
function testB()
    warning('testB');
end
```

I already tried :

```
w = warning ('off','all');%%
try
    testA()
catch ME
    assert(length(ME.message) > 0)
end
w = warning ('on','all');
```

and also lastwarn

```
lastwarn('');

% Do your fitting
    testA()

% Check which warning occured
 [msgstr, msgid] = lastwarn;
switch msgid
   case 'testA'
   error(msgstr);
end
```

But I have got the last warning message which is 'testB' in msgstr and I need to get the 'Test A' warning message.
Any idea?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this well programmatically. Warnings aren't really for control flow.

You can't catch warnings with `try`/`catch`. That's only for errors (aka "exceptions").

If this is your code, your best bet is to modify `testB` so that it returns an additional output argument about the warnings it raised, or the conditions indicated by these warnings. Then have your `testA` pass those along in some structure in another output argument.

If you're just trying to stop at the warning in the debugger, you could accomplish this by adding *identifiers* to your warnings, disabling just the one in `testA`, and then doing a `dbstop if warning`.

```
function testA()
    warning('myproject:TestA', 'testA');
    testB();
end

function testB()
    warning('myproject:TestB', 'testB');
end
```

Then:

```
warning off myproject:TestA
dbstop if warning
testA
```

If you really want to programmatically get at the warning, use the same approach of adding identifiers to your warnings, disable just `myproject:TestA`, and then use `lastwarn` to grab the warning that does arise.